# Permuting "123456728905"

Tags: permutations

In how many ways can `123456728905`be permuted such that, neither two 2's nor two 5's are adjacent to each other ?

I'm really confused how to ensure those conditions?

0 is allowed to come as the first. Consider these are simple characters, not as a whole number.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Did you try to find all possible numbers minus all numbers that of two 2's or two 5's adjacent to each other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Calculate the number of ways in which the two $2's$ and the two $5's$ are always adjacent to each other. Subtract this from the total possible permutations.

Total possible permutations: $\frac{12!}{2!*2!}$

Now group the two $2's$ together and the two $5's$ together. So you have a total of $10$ strings now in place of $12$. So total possible permutations: $10!$

Required permutations would then be: $\frac{12!}{2!*2!} - 10!$

Comment: 12! - 10! will be the answer in that case ?

Comment: Divided by (12!-10!) / (2! * 2!) ?

Comment: Nope. Take care of the $0$ that is present. It cannot occupy the first place anytime.

Comment: No,i told you that,'0' is possible ! Please read the question carefully ? Consider them as just characters !

Comment: Cool sir ! :D Thanks understood :D

Comment: Your answer is almost correct except that $10!$ has nothing in denominator.

Comment: No problem. Here to help out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12798/discussion-between-vaidy-mit-and-lsp)